# How to style multiple bootstrap buttons?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, styles

I have some bootstrap button issues. Firstly, if you take a look at my buttons on the bottom of this page; http://1800daysdev.flywheelsites.com/my-baby/ they are the correct size they need to be. However if you take a look at this page; http://1800daysdev.flywheelsites.com/ the button in the hero image is for some reason inheriting the height values from the buttons on the "my baby" page. How would I get the button on the hero image back to normal and have a different height than the one on the "my baby" page? Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Check to make sure that all of the opening and closing of tags is consistent. I had an instance where I had <button end with ></a> etc which caused a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

In `css` class where you are defining the style properties of `button` in hero image, add `!important` after the `height` attribute.
Like this `height: SIZE !important;`
I hope this helps you.

Comment: My issue is that my button on my hero image is inheriting the styles from the buttons on the "my baby" page and i cannot figure out why. Please look at the links that I included in the first post that I originally posted.

Comment: sorry i could not reply to your comment earlier. i see your problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you modified the height using `.btn { height: 80px }`. This means each and every button assigned the class btn will have a height of 80 pixels if you don't overwrite it accordingly.

In your CSS just add `#hero .btn { height: auto; }`

Comment: that worked great but now how do i get the buttons on the my baby page to be a height of 80px without it making other buttons throughout the site also 80px?

Comment: am i able to put a col-md-4 class within another col-md-4 class? im confused on how i can do this. I have 2 seperate buttons and they both have the class of btn so how can i get each individual button have its own style?

Comment: just add `style="height: auto"` inside the button tag of the one which should not be affected by the 80px height